# Async function as Decorator on Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-decorators

I have a Discord.py Command, I want to make a custom permission handler.

My Command:

```py
@commands.command()
@custom_permission("administrator")
async def example(self, ctx, args):
    ...
```

In this case, `@custom_permission()` is the Permission handler, now how do I make it work for a decorator that in async def?

The Decorator Function:

```py
async def custom_permission(permission):
    
    async def predicate(ctx, permission):
        if ctx.author.id in config.owners:
            return True

        elif permission == "administrator":
            if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
                return True

            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, description=f"You do not meet the required guild permissions the command \"`{ctx.command.name}`\" requires to be executed.\n\nYou need `{permission.upper()}` Permission in this Guild to be able to execute/run/use this command.", color=242424)
                embed.set_author(name="Insufficient Permissions", icon_url=config.forbidden_img)
                embed.set_footer(text="Numix", icon_url=config.logo)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        elif permission == "manage_messages":
            if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                return True

            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, description=f"You do not meet the required guild permissions the command \"`{ctx.command.name}`\" requires to be executed.\n\nYou need `{permission.upper()}` Permission in this Guild to be able to execute/run/use this command.", color=242424)
                embed.set_author(name="Insufficient Permissions", icon_url=config.forbidden_img)
                embed.set_footer(text="Numix", icon_url=config.logo)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        elif permission == "kick":
            if ctx.author.guild_permissions.kick:
                return True

            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, description=f"You do not meet the required guild permissions the command \"`{ctx.command.name}`\" requires to be executed.\n\nYou need `{permission.upper()}` Permission in this Guild to be able to execute/run/use this command.", color=242424)
                embed.set_author(name="Insufficient Permissions", icon_url=config.forbidden_img)
                embed.set_footer(text="Numix", icon_url=config.logo)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        elif permission == "ban":
            if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban:
                return True
                
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, description=f"You do not meet the required guild permissions the command \"`{ctx.command.name}`\" requires to be executed.\n\nYou need `{permission.upper()}` Permission in this Guild to be able to execute/run/use this command.", color=242424)
                embed.set_author(name="Insufficient Permissions", icon_url=config.forbidden_img)
                embed.set_footer(text="Numix", icon_url=config.logo)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        elif permission == "manage_guild":
            if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_guild:
                return True

            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, description=f"You do not meet the required guild permissions the command \"`{ctx.command.name}`\" requires to be executed.\n\nYou need `{permission.upper()}` Permission in this Guild to be able to execute/run/use this command.", color=242424)
                embed.set_author(name="Insufficient Permissions", icon_url=config.forbidden_img)
                embed.set_footer(text="Numix", icon_url=config.logo)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        

    return commands.check(predicate(ctx, permission))
```

Now, how do I make this work?
I can't change it to a normal function, because If I did that, then I can't send the embed message when the permission requirement is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Decorator syntax:

```py
@decorator
def function():
    ...
```

is just syntax sugar for this:

```py
def function():
    ...
function = decorator(function)
```

2. An async function is a function that returns a coroutine.

```
In [1]: async def foo():
   ...:     return 42
   ...: 

In [2]: await foo()
Out[2]: 42

In [3]: foo()
Out[3]: <coroutine object foo at 0x7f7ca626da40>
```

So when you do

```py
@an_async_function("argument")
async def foo():
    ...
```

`an_async_function("argument")` will be a coroutine object, which you are trying to call.

3. `commands.check` expects an async function, while you're passing in the call to that function.

What you can do is:

a) use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to partially apply the `predicate` function to the `permissions` argument:

```py
async def _check_permission(ctx, permission):
    ...

def custom_permission(permission):

    return commands.check(partial(_check_permission, permission=permission))
```

b) Just use the `permission` that you pass in the decorator inside `predicate`.

```py
def custom_permission(permission):
    
    async def predicate(ctx):
        ...  # use `permission` here

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Comment: Would you be up for a chat? My Discord is `Benitz Original#1317`.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to make the outer-most function asynchronous, however the `predicate` function *can* be a coroutine

```py
def custom_permission(permission):
    async def predicate(ctx):
        ...
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

Keep in mind that the `predicate` coroutine can only take one argument, `ctx` (the arguments are passed internally in the `commands.check` method, you do *not* pass them yourself) If you want to access the other arguments use `ctx.args`.

Comment: When the args are in `custom_permission` decorator, will I be able to get it in `ctx.args`?

Comment: You can still use the `permission` argument. By "to access the other arguments use `ctx.args`" I mean the *actual command* arguments.